# iPhone app crashes when attempting to access appDelegate member

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm an Objective-C newbie and I'm studying iPhone programming.

In my **appDelegate**, in the `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method, I've a class member (@syntethized) called **databasePath**.

I set its value this way:

```
databasePath = [self copyDatabaseToDocuments];
```

I copied the entire **copyDatabaseToDocuments** method from a wonderful book by Alasdair Allan and made very little changes (the name of the db is the only thing I changed):

```
-(NSString *)copyDatabaseToDocuments{
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDb.sqlite"];
    //
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        NSString *bundlePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDb.sqlite"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:filePath error:nil];
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

I NSLog the **databasePath** and I regularly get its value (it is a string path and it is not null) after the assignment.

Then, I have a method `-(NSMutableArray*)readDatabase:(char*)querySQL` I call from a ViewController through a delegate reference.

Anything works fine if -inside this last method- I assign again the value of databasePath.

But, if I don't assign it again AND I want to use its value (that I suppose it was set in the `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method) the app crashes.

Why?

Comment: Can you write the definition of the @property in header file for databasePath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your @property for databasePath looks like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *databasePath;
```

And then set it in this way:

```
self.databasePath = [self copyDatabaseToDocuments];
```

It is probably crashing because copyDatabaseToDocuments returns an autoreleased string, and unless you use the self. notation to set databasePath, that autoreleased string can go away at any time.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, since you don't show the relevant code, you are not retaining the value of `databasePath`. You assign it directly to the ivar in your code sample above, yet the method you show returns an autoreleased string.

I'll guess your property is defined as `retain` or `copy`. You should therefore set the value as

```
self.databasePath = [self copyDatabaseToDocuments];
```

This will then retain or copy the value for you. Synthesizing property accessors does you no good if you don't *use* them!

Comment: Thanks very much: the fact is I'm not still very comfortable with memory management (I only have 1 month of XCode/Objective-C/iPhone experience)...

Comment: You'll get there :) there's plenty of good info out there, and it does boil down to about four simple rules which are mentioned in lots of SO answers on the topic.

Comment: Furthermore, for a person who is learning now, it does not help very much (it's really very confusing) anything related to Automatic Reference Counting and Storyboards. You don't exactly know what you'd better learn...